# Number of elements done from a to-do list

Tags: javascript, codepen

I'm trying to put on the screen that items from a list that I have done.
I came up with this function:

```js
function countDone() {
  let numberOfDone = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++) {
    if (todoList[i].isDone === true) {
      numberOfDone = numberOfDone + 1
    }
    return numberOfDone
  }
}
    
function printCountDone() {
  let f = countDone()
  document.querySelector('#todo-done').innerHTML = f
}
```

I don't know if the function is wrong or if I'm just calling it at the wrong place.
I saw some similar posts here, but I couldn't understand (I'm a newbie, sorry in advance)
Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/lodesousa/pen/jOLOeLr

Comment: "I don't know if the function is wrong" – what behavior are you expecting to happen, and what is happening instead? Try describing in your question what exactly is going wrong, and how we can help :)

Comment: Move `return numberOfDone` down a line (right now you're exiting the function inside the for loop). Next, you need to actually call `printCountDone()`, at some point after toggling `todoList[selectedTodoIndex].isDone`

Comment: Note that you can shorten this a lot: the entire code in the question can be replaced with `document.querySelector('#todo-done').innerHTML = todoList.filter(todo => todo.isDone).length` which will also fix both issues.

Comment: @Leland Nothing is happening :/ What I want is to update the "Done" part. So if I checked 2 items in a list of 6 items, the "Done" part should have a number 2.

Comment: @ChrisG But in what part of the code should I put this? `document.querySelector('#todo-done').innerHTML = todoList.filter(todo => todo.isDone).length`

Comment: Just replace the two functions with it. The line needs to run after the clicked todo is toggled.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris G has already covered this in their comments, but I wanted to explore what's happening with you in greater depth.

Here's the code you have, in plain English:

```
function countDone:
  create variable "numberOfDone" and set to 0

  iterate over all todos. for each todo:
    if the todo is done:
      increase variable "numberOfDone" by 1
    return variable numberOfDone
  end iteration
end function
```

Spot the error? Check out the indentation. Spoiler: *The function isn't returning anything.*

You're returning `numberOfDone` *every iteration of the `for` loop* rather than right at the end of the function like you want.

Returning a value at the wrong point in a function is an incredibly common programming error – I'd bet every programmer has faced this at one point. That's something that you should think about going forward: checking if a function returns anything is an excellent starting place when debugging functions.

Anyway, cheers, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Congrats on your first question!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Leland!! I will pay more attention to that in the future! (: